# Login and Register Requests in API's

Tags: rest, authentication, post, get

I'm currently working on a small project where I need to create login and register functionalities for a web application. A colleague of mine had the opinion, that a login request should be done with a post request where the user credentials are stored in the body of the request. I was used to do login requests with a Get-Request where the login credentials are stored in the authentication header (e.g. with Basic-Authentication). So I've read some threads and most of them say, that a POST-Request is better than a GET-Request for login. But also some threads said, that it is better to store user credentials in a request header instead of the body. In case the credentials are stored in the header I don't understand why a GET-Request should be better than a POST-Request.

So I was wondering what you think. What are the benefits/disadvantages of Login with POST-Request and User Credentials stored in the Request-Body compared to storing them in the header via Base-Authentication (encrypted with Base64).

Thanks for any opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A POST is preferable for login request, because the authentication information will be sent in the HTTP messages body rather than the URL. Although it will still be sent plain text, unless you're encrypting via HTTPS.

GET method data is sent to the server followed by the URL which will be seen to everyone.

Both GET and POST method are used to transfer data from client to server in HTTP protocol but main difference between POST and GET method is that GET carries request parameter appended in URL string, while POST carries request parameter in message body which makes it more secure way of transferring data from client to server in HTTP protocol.