# MongoDB JS 304 StatusCode

Tags: javascript

First of all I'm extremely sorry but i can't figure out what the title should be,
I'm trying to send data to MongoDB Database but for some reason, I keep getting 304 status code, I tried searching it on the internet but I couldn't find a solution, and was hard for me to understand, can you guys please help me?

Here's the data I'm trying to send to DB

```
  const router = require("express").Router();
  const User = require("../models/User");



 router.get("/register", async (req,res) => {
 const user = await new User ({
 username:"username",
  email:"User@email.com",
  password:"123456"
  })
 await user.save();
 res.send("okk!");

});


module.exports = router;
```

//
MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66813163/6036546) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If ang other operation to Mongoose doesn't work too, I guess your Mongoose connection part has problem. Did you check your connection option(URL), or MongoDB connectivity itself?
Try same operation on MongoShell, or Compass, etc.

Comment: And, by the way, if you intended to service "Sign up" API, I think it is better to use HTTP method "POST", not "GET" because of security problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874983/login-and-register-requests-in-apis

Comment: Last, If the connectivity is not a core reason for this problem(means you can receive 304 status code always, no matter of Mongoose), It may be caused by Caching.

Comment: See https://blog.airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/304-not-modified

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32351548)